# Laravel 4 - Use Class Functions inside Views

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, frameworks

I was wondering if it is possible to use classes and define functions in a controller file , then call these methods inside views.

Right now :

I'm just writing normal php functions then inluding them inside the views like :

PHP FILE

```
function viewProfile() {

    function getUsername() {

    $username = Auth::user()->username;

    return $username;
    }

    function getName() {

    $name = Auth::user()->name;

    return $name;
    }

    function getEmail() {

    $email = Auth::user()->email;

    return $email;
    }

}
```

Views File :

```
<?php

include(app_path().'/scripts/profile.php'); 

viewProfile();

?>

<td><?php echo getUsername() ?></td>
```

I want to write it in classes instead like :

```
public class profile {


public static $username = Auth::user()->username;
public static $name = Auth::user()->]name;
public static $email = Auth::user()->email;

    function getUsername() {

    return $username;
    }

    function getName() {

    return $name;
    }


    function getEmail() {

    return $email;
    }


}
```

I tried creating a controller file and using the above code but doesn;t seem to work - i guess controllers can be used for routing functions only.

Is there any way to use the class above and link the view , so i can use its methods ?

Comment: Are you really nesting functions inside your `viewProfile()` function?!?

Comment: Your profile class looks just like a model, and all the functionality you do, you can do just from the view like {{ Auth::user()->username }} so i think you need to start thinking more in framework style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use blade to get what you want...

in your view you do...

```
<div>username: {{ Auth::user()->username }}</div>
<div>name: {{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>
<div>email: {{ Auth::user()->email }}</div>
```

And that is mainly it, no need for classes or anything else.

**TIP** To activate blade you just add the .blade.php extenstion